# Virtualhost in Apache (wildcard and static domain)

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, virtualhost

I have some odd situation. I wan to make different DirectoryRoot for one domain.

example.com -> /dir1
www.example.com -> /dir1

*.example.com -> /dir2

I'm trying settings with NameVirtualHost and ServerAlias. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like...

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot = /var/www/dir1
    ServerName d1.example.com
<VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot = /var/www/example
    ServerName example.com
<VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot = /var/www/someotherdir
    ServerName other.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
<VirtualHost>
```

Taken from my working setup (obviously trimmed a little!)

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot = /var/www/wildcard
      ServerName other.example.com
      ServerAlias *.example.com
    <VirtualHost>

This is not working. It is only forking for other.example.com. When I'm browsking to aaaa.example.com is is loading content form /var/www/example not from /var/www/wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can use `apache`'s `location` directive to force the directory-root

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir1
<VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir2
<VirtualHost>
```

**Remember the first `VirtualHost` takes precedence.**